# How to make all the inserts and THEN check the foreign key constraints? (SQL transaction fails with foreign key constraint)

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have two tables:

[image]

Each **deck** (of cards) always belongs to some player (one player can have 1..* decks). Moreover, each player **always** has one (and one only) active deck.

I want to add a new player, but if I just execute `INSERT INTO players(...) VALUES (...)`, I won't have the `active_deck_id` that should be inserted in this query. The same way, if I start from `decks`, I won't have `player_id`.

That's why I decided to use the transaction (within a procedure):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_player` (IN login VARCHAR(255), IN password VARCHAR(255), 
    OUT player_id INT(11))
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO `players` (id, `login`, `password`, registered, last_logged, active_deck_id) 
    VALUES ('', login, pass, now(), now(), 0);

SET player_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO `decks` (id, name, player_id) VALUES ('', `sample deck`, player_id);

COMMIT;
END
END
```

Then I've just called it with:

```
set @login = 'mylogin';
set @pass = 'pass';
call add_player(@login, @pass, @id);
```

... but I got an error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`game`.`players`, CONSTRAINT `active_deck` FOREIGN KEY (`active_deck_id`) REFERENCES `decks` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

So, **how to make all the inserts and THEN check the foreign key constraints?** Because after first insert the constraints are supposed to be broken, but after the whole transaction they should be ok.

The SQL for my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game`.`decks` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `player_id`),
  INDEX `player` (`player_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `player`
    FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`)
    REFERENCES `game`.`players` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game`.`players` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `registered` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `last_logged` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `active_deck_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `active_deck` (`active_deck_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `active_deck`
    FOREIGN KEY (`active_deck_id`)
    REFERENCES `game`.`decks` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

before you make your inserts, then turn it on by setting the value to 1.